# How to copy files from a linux agent to windows agent in Azure DevOps release pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, agent, azure-pipelines-tasks, azure-pipelines-release-task

I have to run a Linux docker image for performing testing in Azure DevOps release pipeline. Hence, I have used;

> Agent Pool : Azure Pipelines and Agent Specification: ubuntu-20.04

for that task. Now, result of this test has to be send as an email. For that 'Send Email' extension in Azure DevOps marketplace can be used. But this is configured only for Windows agent.

So, there is a requirement to run two agent jobs, one for Linux and other Windows. How can I access the report file generated in first job, to send email in second.

Had tried publishing pipeline artifacts, but it didn't worked as artifacts are not supported in release.